# laravel-5.8:The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to add products in cart but it says: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.. (View: \resources\views\product\detail.blade.php), I wants that by clicking the addtocart it redirect me to that age with products,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...…………………………………..,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

route:

```
  Route::get('cart', 'Admin\ProductController@cart')->name('product.cart');

  Route::get('/addToCart/{product}', 'Admin\ProductController@addToCart')->name('addToCart');
```

controller:

```
  public function cart()
  {
    if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return view('products.cart');
    }
    $cart = Session::has('cart');
    return view('product.cart', compact('cart'));
  }

  public function addToCart(Product $product, Request $request)
  {
    if(empty(Auth::user()->email)){
        $data['email'] = '';    
    }else{
        $data['email'] = Auth::user()->email;
    }

    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $qty = $request->qty ? $request->qty : 1;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->addProduct($product);
    Session::put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Product $product->title has been successfully added to Cart');
    }
```

view:

```
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('addToCart') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="btn-addcart-product-detail size9 trans-0-4 m-t-10 m-b-10">
                            @if($product->product_status == 1)
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <button class="flex-c-m sizefull bg1 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                                Add to Cart
                            </button>
                            @else Out Of Stock @endif
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

model:

```
  <?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Cart
  {
private $contents;
private $totalQty;
private $contentsPrice;

public function __construct($oldCart){
    if ($oldCart) {
        $this->contents = $oldCart->contents;
        $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
        $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
    }
}

public function addProduct($product, $qty){
    $products = ['qty' => 0, 'price' => $product->price, 'product' => $product];
    if ($this->contents) {
        if (array_key_exists($product->slug, $this->contents)) {
            $product = $this->contents[$product->slug];
        }
    }

    $products['qty'] +=$qty;
    $products['price'] +=$product->price * $product['qty'];
    $this->contents[$product->slug] = $product;
    $this->totalQty+=$qty;
    $this->totalPrice += $product->price;
}

public function getContents()
{
    return $this->contents;
}
public function getTotalQty()
{
    return $this->totalQty;
}
public function getTotalPrice()
{
    return $this->totalPrice;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your form method in the view is `POST` but you don't have a post route.

Second, the route that you have defined expect a parameter(product) you can change the form action as below BUT I think you want to send the user to another page so you can use a link instead of form.

Here's the form action:

```
action="{{ route('addToCart', $product->id) }}"
```

And if you want to use link, you can do something like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('addToCart', $product->id) }}">.....</a>
```

Comment: now that error has removed but when I clicked on add to cart btn then it says The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: I change it to get but still same how can I use a like should u prefer to tell me

Comment: now my code is paste.ofcode.org/3aT3Cb7mThrzB75nRkcf9vK but nthingis happening by clicking on it

Comment: There was a typo in my code. First change the `hred` to `href` and you can remove the button tag and add the classes to a tag.

Comment: Too few arguments to function App\Cart::addProduct(), 1 passed in app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController.php on line 193 and exactly 2 expected    https://ibb.co/5LpNj96

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be **POST**. In the form, you're calling it Post method but in route.php file, you defined as get to change it as `Route::post`

```
Route::post('/addToCart/{product}', 'Admin\ProductController@addToCart')->name('addToCart');
```

In addition, your route.php file expecting `{product}` so you need to pass it in form `route` so your action be like `{{ route('addToCart',$product->id) }}`

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('addToCart',$product->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Comment: by making post in both route and form it says: 419 page expired and by making get at both sides it says: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Comment: pass `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` under the form.

Comment: Edited answer, please check.

Comment: Class 'App\Admin\Auth' not found at "if" line public function addToCart(Product $product, Request $request)
    {
        if(empty(Auth::user()->email)){

Comment: Add this line above you class definition: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: `use Auth;` at top after `namespace`.

Comment: Too few arguments to function App\Cart::addProduct(), 1 passed in app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController.php on line 193 and exactly 2 expected    https://ibb.co/5LpNj96

Comment: What did you try before putting this error? at least try from your side then put it here.